Laravel echo TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channel')
I'm using Laravel for backend and Vue for frontend. I'm also using Vite as my bundler and laravel echo for broadcasting. I'm trying to create a websocket to show newly added comments in real time.
this is the function for broadcasting in my app.vue:
    listenForNewComments() {
        window.Echo.channel('comments')
            .listen('CommentCreated', (e) => {
                this.newComments.push(e.comment);
                    console.log(e)
            });
    }

In my .env file I configured pusher information for vite:
VITE_PUSHER_APP_ID=1816356
VITE_APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST=
VITE_PUSHER_APP_SECRET="${PUSHER_APP_SECRET}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT=443
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME=https
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

My bootstrap.js:
import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
    encrypted: true,
});

channels.php:
Broadcast::channel('comments', function () {
    return true;
});


And this is the event `CommentCreated.php'
class CommentCreated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $comment;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('comments');
    }
}


Obviosly I'm missing something and I tried to find a solution whole day. Function listenForNewComments I got from chatGPT and I'm sure that it made a mistake but I cannot find it. I found the same issue here but thread creator didn't even explained his solution. Please, help me!

hi, did you import class Broadcast to your CommentCreated.php' file?
